# Integrating R code with a web server

Tags: r, thrift, rpy2, rapache, deployr

Overview:
Need to integrate R library with a web server written in python. I have explored some of the options commonly mentioned on different blogs and stack overflow threads. The threads I have come across compare libraries like Rpy2 and pypeR and provide specific answers to integrate R and python. What I am looking for is a general solution so that the R code can be accessed by a multitude of programming languages/clients (for future extensibility).

Requirements:

1. R code should run separately to handle heavy computation and not be embedded into the application server.
2. R module should be scalable and easily maintainable. ex- any change to the application server (written in python) should not trigger changes in the R code.
3. R module can be used as an API for further application development using web frameworks other than python.

Options already explored:

1. rpy2, pypeR: One option is to write a separate python server and let that server handle R code using rpy2. The app server can send requests to the second server.
2. Rserve and pyRserve: Use Rserve and pyRserve client to communicate between R and python.
3. Apache Thrift and Protocol Buffer: rprotobuf is an interface for R to make it work with Protocol Buffer but I could not find any support for R in Apache Thrift. Will something like Thrift or protocol buffer be better than creating an R server.
4. Rapache and Rook: Use Rapache and Rook package in R to setup a server for processing requests.
5. deployR: Created by Revolution Analytics.

Which among these would be an ideal choice or any other option which is not in the list?

Comment: Write an R script and run it using `call`? Any language can do that.

Comment: Modified the first line to clarify the problem. Its not just 1 R script but an entire library that I need to integrate with the web server. And I don't want to call R scripts specifically from the app server. A general solution, which allows me use the library like an API, is required.

Comment: If we talk about a *.lib or similar which can be included into C or C++ this would be the way to go. Could that work for your case? If not, why not? "*R code should run separately to handle heavy computation and not be embedded into the application server*" I don't see an issue with having a thin host application around it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider the following ?

- Python has a package to interface with Thrift / create thrift servers.
- Rpy2 is an interface to R (and arguably the fastest one).

`web server   <--->   Thrift server
(Python)             (Python + rpy2)`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **Apache Thrift** bindings:

- First, Apache Thrift does not have native bindings for R<sup>1)</sup>.
- Second, from what I read so far (I am not an R user), there are plenty of options to integrate R into other host languages. Thrift offers support for C++, C, Java, Python and a plethora of other targets and languages, 20+ in total. So it seems possible to create a host application offering the Thrift API and housing the R stuff.

---

<sup>1)</sup> <sub>Today. I can't look into the future, and things change quickly sometimes.</sub>

Comment: Will creating a host application housing R and then using Thrift to connect it to other languages scale up? Also is there any specific benefit of using this kind of a setup over the others? Protocol Buffer has an interface for R. How does Protocol Buffer compare against Apache Thrift?